# AS3 Animation with Bitmaps

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, bitmap, frame

I'm doing an animation class in ActionScript 3 and would like to know the most efficient way to do it.
Currently what I do is get an image (sprite sheet) and keep all the frames in an array of Bitmaps, then add each frame as a child and I put setVisible = false except the frame I have to show.

The other way I can think of is to have only one Bitmap added as a child and every time frame has to be changed, I copy the pixels to the Bitmap using copyPixels function.

There is somewhat more efficient than either of these alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep all your frames in a vector of `BitmapData`. Then use a single `Bitmap` and change it's `bitmapData` property when you want to change frames.

Answer (score 0):

`Copypixels` is quite fast.

There's an excellent comparison of rendering methods [here at 8bitrocket.com](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2007/12/23/flash-as3-speed-tests-rendering-and-update-models/); I would suggest giving it a read.